# SwiftyStoreKit: 'contentURL' and 'transaction' were deprecated in iOS 16.0: Hosted content is no longer supported

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftystorekit

Xcode is warning me that `'contentURL' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Hosted content is no longer supported` and `x'transaction' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: Hosted content is no longer supported`...how can rewrite this SwiftyStoreKit block to silence the warning?

```
  SwiftyStoreKit.updatedDownloadsHandler = { downloads in
            
            // contentURL is not nil if downloadState == .finished
            let contentURLs = downloads.compactMap { $0.contentURL }
            if contentURLs.count == downloads.count {
                print("Saving: \(contentURLs)")
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(downloads[0].transaction)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems that `SKDownload` is deprecated https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skdownload So check `SwiftyStoreKit` if they are working on the support of the replacement, no? But it seems related to StoreKit2 as said in the ReadMe

Comment: @Larme thanks the library isn't actively supported anymore unfortunately.  I need to migrate to StoreKit2 but am not ready to quite yet.